# Whether a item in org mode is a plain todo item

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I am customizing `org-clock-in-hook` to do some action after a item is clocked in.But first I need to make sure whether the clocked-in item is **a plain todo item** or **a agenda item (scheduled or deadlined)**.

I has dig through the org mode source,but related code is long and it's all regular expressions.

Any guy can provide a elegant solution?

Answer (score 1):

The scheduled and deadline status of an entry is contained in the `SCHEDULED` and `DEADLINE` special properties.  As with other properties, you can read them with `org-entry-get`: `(org-entry-get (point) "SCHEDULED")`.  It returns the timestamp (as a string) if there is one and `nil` otherwise.